# How to count at multiple levels in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry for not being able to provide with the code. I solved this problem  in SAS, now I want to do the same in Python.

In the following dataframe, there are several instances of consecutive zeros:

```
Date        Time      Ask       Bid       Day     Price     Return

xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Mon     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Tue     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       0
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       xxxx
xxx         xxx       xxx       xxx       Wed     xxx       xxxx
```

I would like to know how many incidents of consecutive zeros in each day, and how many zeros in  each incident are there for each day. For example, if we look at Wednesday, we see that there are 2 incidents of consecutive zeros: in the 1st one there 2 zeros, and in the 2nd one, there are 3. For Tuesday there's only one incident of consecutive zeros having 3 zeros.

So, I would like to have an output like the following one:

```
Day  Incident   Count_0

Mon    1          2
Mon    2          3
Tue    1          3
Wed    1          2
Wed    2          3
```

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#filter 0 values - if strings use '0'
mask = df['Return'].eq(0)
#consecutive groups for 0
g1 = df['Return'].ne(df['Return'].shift()).cumsum()
#consecutive groups for Days
g2 = df['Day'].ne(df['Day'].shift()).cumsum()
#filter by 0 rows and aggregate counts
df1 = (g2[mask].groupby([g1, df['Day']])
               .size()
               .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
               .reset_index(name='Count_0'))
#filter out unique rows (count == 1)
df1 = df1[df1['Count_0'].ne(1)].copy()
#Incidentcolumn by counter by new consecutive Days
g3 = df1['Day'].ne(df1['Day'].shift()).cumsum()
df1.insert(1, 'Incident', g3.groupby(g3).cumcount() + 1)
print (df1)
   Day  Incident  Count_0
0  Mon         1        2
1  Mon         2        3
2  Tue         1        3
5  Wed         1        2
6  Wed         2        3
```

Answer (score 1):

An Idea is to set the column as a string and create incidents with list comprehension.

```
x=np.where(df['Return']=="0",'1','0')
df['Incident']=pd.DataFrame({"column1":[['xxxx'] if j=='' else [str(i)]*len(j) for i,j in enumerate(re.findall(r'(1*)', ''.join(x)))]}).explode('column1').fillna('xxxx').reset_index()['column1']
final=df.query("group!='xxxx'").groupby(["Day",'Incident']).count()[["Return"]]
final=final.query("Return!=1").reset_index()
final.assign(Incident=final.groupby('Day').cumcount()+1)


   Day  Incident  Return
0  Mon         1       2
1  Mon         2       3
2  Tue         1       3
3  Wed         1       2
4  Wed         2       3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['06-04-2020', '06-04-2020', '06-04-2020', '06-04-2020', '07-04-2020', '07-04-2020', '08-04-2020'],
                   'day': ['Mon', 'Mon', 'Mon', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Tue', 'Wed'],
                   'value': [0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3]})
print(df)

result = []
for grp in df.groupby(by=['date', 'day']):
    grp_counts = [(i, len(list(j))) for i, j in groupby(list(grp[1]['value']))]
    for a, b in enumerate([x[1] for x in grp_counts if x[0]==0]):
        result.append([grp[0][0], grp[0][1], a+1, b])

print(pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['date', 'day', 'seq', 'count']))
```

DataFrame:

```
         date  day  value
0  06-04-2020  Mon      0
1  06-04-2020  Mon      0
2  06-04-2020  Mon      1
3  06-04-2020  Mon      0
4  07-04-2020  Tue      2
5  07-04-2020  Tue      0
6  08-04-2020  Wed      3
```

Result:

```
         date  day  seq  count
0  06-04-2020  Mon    1      2
1  06-04-2020  Mon    2      1
2  07-04-2020  Tue    1      1
```